# EdgeStyle on a LayeredGraphPlot

Tags: function, plot, graph, wolfram-mathematica, edge-list

I'm using the `LayeredGraphPlot` function of Mathematica, and I would like to customize my edges and vertex using `EdgeStyle` and `VertexStyle`. But these two functions don't exist for a `LayeredGraphPlot`.

In fact I have a list of weight for the edges, and I want to plot dashed edges for the smallest one, thick red edges for the biggest, and normal blue for the others. (and quite the same with the vertex : the more a word is used, the darker the vertex is)

How can I do with the `EdgeRenderingFunction` and the `VertexRenderingFunction`? I don't really understand how pure functions can work in this case.